# Plot 3d spherical coordinates without converting to cartesian first

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I have a list of 3d spherical coordinates (`r`, `theta`,`phi`) that I want to plot using matplotlib, is there a way to do it without having to convert them to cartesian coordinates?

Comment: The simple answer is (afaik) no. You can write a simple function to do the conversion, though, and then always just import that and use it to plot with.  That's what I've always done.